# IP Cameras and their supported protocol

Tags: rtsp, bonjour, upnp, ip-camera, rtsp-client

Do the majority of IP cameras support RTSP?

Also, apart from using uPnP and Bonjour are there any other ways of detecting IP cameras on the local network?

Comment: Majority - perhaps yes. All - definitely no. Some cameras implement vendor specific discovery (esp. using UDP broadcast).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I liked your project in CodeProject using VLC.  Have not got it to work with the 64bit version of VLC yet but they say it is just experimental.  Would it be also safe to assume the majority of IP cameras support uPNP?

Comment: I'd say many support UPnP but it's not always enabled by default. So it appears that both RTSP and UPnP is something frequently available, but still not something you can safely rely on availability of.

Comment: OK - so any recommendations on how to design an application that will display an RTSP (I am using ur nVLC - thanks) when i do not know the make and model of an IP camera or a DVR?  I dont mind prompting the User for the password and Username and i can compile a list of common RTSP connection strings. The thing i am unsure of is 'dicovering' these devices on the local network in the 1st place.  thanks for ur time btw

Comment: Prompting for user/pass and possibly IP address, you will have to maintain internal database of known devices and additional parameters. It's not easy, and there is no universal way. ONVIF compliance helps a bit, if the device is compliant.

Comment: hi, thanks again for replying. This is exactly the route i have taken..